# Integral and polar coordinate transformation

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis, polar-coordinates

I want to calculate

$$\int \limits_{\mathbb{R^2}} e^{i \ x \cdot \xi} \varphi(\xi) \ \ d\xi$$ using polar coordinate transformation. Where $x,\xi \in \mathbb{R}^2$ , $\varphi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ (schwartz function) and $x \cdot \xi$ denote the inner product.

I want to use the fact that $x \cdot \xi = \vert x \vert \vert \xi \vert \cos \theta$ where $\cos \theta= \cos \angle x,\xi$.

$$\int \limits_{\mathbb{R^2}} e^{i \ x \cdot \xi} \varphi(\xi) \ \ d\xi = \int \limits_{0}^{\infty} \int \limits_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{\vert x \vert r \cos\theta} \varphi(?) \ d\theta \ dr$$

The idea was to point one of the vectors to the north-pole.
My first question is how to adapt $\varphi$ and the second is does $\varphi$ have to be rotation invariant ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\varphi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ let
$$ f(x) = \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^2} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} x \cdot \xi} \varphi(\xi) \, \mathrm{d} \xi  \, . $$
If we introduce polar coordinates $\xi_1 = r \cos(\theta)$ , $\xi_2 = r \sin(\theta)$ and take into account the Jacobian of this transformation, we obtain
$$ f(x) = \int \limits_0^\infty \int \limits_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} r (x_1 \cos(\theta) + x_2 \sin(\theta))} \,\varphi(r \cos(\theta), r \sin(\theta)) \, r \, \mathrm{d} \theta \,\mathrm{d} r \, .$$
This is the best we can do for functions $\varphi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ (or $\varphi \in L^1 (\mathbb{R}^2)$) that are not invariant under rotations.

However, if $\varphi$ does have this symmetry, further simplifications are possible. Let $R \in \operatorname{SO}(2)$ be a rotation matrix satisfying $R x = |x| e_1$ . Then the change of variables $\eta = R \xi$ (which has unit Jacobian) yields
$$ f(x) = \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^2} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} x \cdot R^{\top} \eta} \varphi(R^\top \eta) \, \mathrm{d} \eta = \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^2} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} |x| \eta_1} \varphi(\eta) \, \mathrm{d} \eta \, , $$
where we have used the rotational invariance of $\varphi$ and the inner product. Now the introduction of polar coordinates for $\eta$ leads to
$$ f(x) = \int \limits_0^\infty \int \limits_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}  |x| r \cos(\theta)} \,\varphi(r \cos(\theta), r \sin(\theta)) \, r \, \mathrm{d} \theta \,\mathrm{d} r = \int \limits_0^\infty \int \limits_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}  |x| r \cos(\theta)} \,\psi(r) \, r \, \mathrm{d} \theta \,\mathrm{d} r \, .$$
Here $\psi$ is the function on $[0,\infty)$ satisfying $\varphi(x) = \psi(|x|)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$. We can integrate with respect to  $\theta$ to find
$$ f(x) = 2 \pi \int \limits_0^\infty \psi(r) \operatorname{J}_0 (r |x|) r \, \mathrm{d} r \,  , $$
where
$$ \operatorname{J}_0 (t) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int \limits_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} t \cos(\theta)} \, \mathrm{d} \theta $$
is the zeroth-order Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: could you explain to me in more detail how you choose the coordinate system in which $x$ points into the positive $\xi_1$-direction ? I don't understand why only in $\xi_1$ direction.

Comment: @McBotto.t Indeed, choosing such a coordinate system is only possible if $\varphi$ is invariant under rotations, so my original answer was wrong. I have edited it accordingly. My apologies.

Comment: I'm sorry but there are still some questions.
I don't understand why we need a rotation that satisfies $Rx=\vert x \vert e_1$
And i don't understand why we get form $\int e^{i \ x \cdot R^{T} \eta} \varphi(R^{T} \eta) d\eta = \int e^{i \ \vert x \vert \eta_1} \varphi d \eta $ I calculated it and when i use the fact that $R^{-1}= R^{T}$. i get with the rotation matrix R form wiki that $\vert R^{-1} (\eta_1,\eta_2)^{T} \vert = \eta_2$ while assuming that $\eta=(0,\eta_2)^{T}$ 
what do i wrong ?

Comment: @McBotto.t If we choose such a rotation, only $|x|$ and one trigonometric function appear in the exponent, which greatly simplifies the calculation in spherical coordinates. Since $\varphi(S \eta) = \varphi(\eta)$ holds for every rotation matrix $S \in \operatorname{SO}(2)$ by rotational symmetry, we have $\varphi(R^\top \eta) = \varphi(\eta)$. Moreover, the invariance of the inner product under rotations implies $x \cdot R^\top \eta = (R x) \cdot (R R^\top \eta) = (|x|e_1) \cdot \eta$, so the two forms of the integral are indeed equal.